# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Problem :

When i try to start my spring application,it throw the following exception and i'm using keycloak 10.0.1 version

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for
>   class [org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties]

Controller

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        model.addObject("message", "Test");
        return model;
    }
}
```

application properties

```
#Spring MVC web config
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=springboot1
keycloak.resource=testproduct-app
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
```

When i include the below dependency in my pom.xml im getting the exception

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found the solution the problem is my maven repository after i delete and mvn clean install i'm able to do the keycloak login.

cheers